# Seeing artifacts on my screen however the issue is not to do with my GPU

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

I'm mostly looking for a confirmation here, I have started seeing artifacts appearing on my monitor screen, originally I suspected this could be down my GPU being on the fritz, however I have just experienced the issues without the monitor even having been plugged into the computer, thus ruling out the possibility that it is down to the GPU.

The artifacts cover the entire screen and essentially only updates what I see on the screen every 30 seconds - 1 minute, after a short while (Ranges between one minute - five minutes) the artifacts cease and go away so long as I have the monitor turned on, when I turn the monitor off, leave it, and then come back to it, the artifacts return.

I have replaced the cable I was using with a completely brand new DVI cable (Switch from HDMI to DVI) which actually made the issue worse, as before it only covered the bottom 25% of the screen, whereas now it covers pretty much the entirety.

Am I right in my belief that this is a sign that the display is essentially dead/dying and needs to be replaced?

Updating post with photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV4AX.jpg

Comment: include a pic eg link to pic on imgur.com

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately I wasn't able to grab a picture of the issue before I made this post, I've tried to get it to recreate however I wasn't able to do so in the moment.

Comment: I have had a quick look on Google to see if I could find a close enough screenshot to my issue and this one is very close, not exactly the same however still very close:

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/199681i14F6CFC4C846D6F8?v=1.0

Comment: If I see the issue occur again (Which I should) I'll try to grab a screenshot of it. It only usually occurs in the mornings or after I leave the screen for about 30 minutes -1 hour.

Comment: To me, it appears that your assumption is right, your display is very likely dying, you have to buy a new one.

Comment: Hi there, here's the photos as promised, as expected it is happening again today.
https://imgur.com/a/17R3GBR

Comment: It essentially starts up like this, and has gone on for the past 10-15 minutes, after that point it has ceased doing this (after a few times of me turning it off/on again and trying to stimulate it with flashing colours (Not a clue if that would make any difference but hey-ho) 

After which the screen then returns back to normal and is usable once again